# json passing function is not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-2

i pass json value my controller is working i checked my controller using break points but my json is not working it didn't responding alert message also not working please some one helpme friends. . .

My jquery

```
  $('#Group').change(function () {
            var name = $('#Tournament').val();   

            $.post("/DataCollection/Fee", { name: name, group: $('#Group').val() }, function (result) {
                alert('hai');
                $('#Fee').val(result.value.Fees);
                $('#Count').val(result.value.NoOfboys);
                $('#CName').empty();
                $('#CName').append($("<option></option>").html("--SELECT--"));
                $.each(result.Cname, function (key, value) {
                    $('#CName').append($("<option></option>").html(value).val(value));
                });

            }, "json");
        });
```

My Controller

```
     public JsonResult Fee(string name, string Group)
    {            
        var value = entity.TblClsGroups.FirstOrDefault(x => x.TName == name && x.GroupName == Group && x.RecordStatus == 1);
        var Cname = entity.TblGroups.Where(x=>x.RecordStatus==1 && x.TName == name && x.GroupName == Group).Select(c=>c.Cid);           
        var getFee = new { Cname, value };
        return Json(getFee, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
return Json(new { Cname = Cname, value = value }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

and in view use them like `result.Cname` and `result.value`

Comment: Have you tried that request goes to action or not in debug? Firstly try for 1 value. if it will work, my example will work for 2 values

Comment: friend my controller is returning value correctly but in my jquery alert message is also not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var getFee = new { Cname = Cname, value = value };
```

Comment: Cname and value both are not same its different datas

Comment: You should set a `debugger;` breakpoint and inspect the returned value.

Comment: Yes it returning value

Comment: What does it return? What does the object look like? Does it have the two properties, `Cname` and `value`. Is it a Json object?

Comment: Yes friend it returning the correct value but my alert message is also not working